# Swift 2.0 Map "Instance member cannot be used on type"

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, fft

I am trying to learn how to create a FFT using swift 2.0 however i am having trouble getting the .map function to compile.

The following code works in a playground but not inside xCode as a member of a swift class.

I get the following error "Instance member 'sineArraySize' cannot be used on type 'FFTAnalyser'

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate

class FFTAnalyser {
    let sineArraySize = 64 // Should be power of two for the FFT

    let frequency1 = 4.0
    let phase1 = 0.0
    let amplitude1 = 2.0

    var sineWave = (0..<sineArraySize).map {
        amplitude1 * sin(2.0 * M_PI / Double(sineArraySize) * Double($0) * frequency1 + phase1)
    }

    func plotArray<T>(arrayToPlot:Array<T>) {
        for x in arrayToPlot {
            print(x)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because `sineWave` tries to access the `self` property `sineArraySize` and others before `self` was initialized (initialization happens after defining the values for properties). To work around this, you can do this:

```
var sineWave : [Double] = []

init() {
    sineWave = (0..<sineArraySize).map {
        amplitude1 * sin(2.0 * M_PI / Double(sineArraySize) * Double($0) * frequency1 + phase1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I had over estimated Swift's ability to automatically initialise variables.

Simply moving all the variables into a method, or using an initialiser solved the problem.